# Application subclass class returns null pointer exception

Tags: android, caching, application-singleton

I am creating an application where i need to load the images for all the components like buttons, logo.. from the server. I am using three classes MemoryCache,FileCache and ImageLoder class from fedors Lazylist example 
https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/tree/master/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist
where we can pass url and View to ImageLoader and load,cache the image etc.

so i want to initialize the ImageLoder class only once in the entire app and reused it in other Activities in order to do that i created a object for it in  my MyGlobalClass extented with Application like this.

```
public class MyGlobalClass extends Application {
    private static Context context;
    private static MyGlobalClass singleton;
    private static ImageLoader imageLoder = new ImageLoader(getAppContext());
    private static String[] urls;

    public MyGlobalClass getInstance() {
        return singleton;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        singleton = this;
        MyGlobalClass .context = getApplicationContext();

        urls = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.urls);
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyGlobalClass .context;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoder;
    }

    public String[] getUrls() {
        return urls;
    }
}
```

I created `<appplication>` field in **AndroidManifest.xml** as

```
<application
    android:name="com.xx.yy.MyGlobalClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
</application>
```

But when I am using it in other activities like creating object of global class I am doing this:

```
MyGlobalClass myGClass = (MyGlobalClass)getApplicationContext(); // null pointer here
```

It's returning a null pointer exception.

I want to access `ImageLoader` in `HomeActivity` like this:

```
ImageButton homeBt = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
ImageLoader imgLoader=(ImageLoader)myGClass.getImageLoader();
String[] urls=myGClass.getUrls();
imgLoader.DisplayImage(urls[1], cameraBt);
```

Can anybody see what is wrong with my code and suggest how to do it? I also created a singleton field but don't know why, and how to use it. Please provide some examples.
I am actually adding the above exception line in activity class before onCreate(), so may be that is the problem..but when i am adding it in onCreate() in HomeActivity it gives me Class cast Exception..cannot cast to android.app.Application to com.xx.yy.MyGlobalClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually iam creating Another "application" tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file unknowingly, the fact is --android:name="com.xx.yy.MyGlobalClass"-- should be added to same "application" tag which you created before if any, 
In Answers for the ClassCastException questions,every body mentioned we need to add  tag with "android:name" property in the ManifestFile..but didn't specify it where..,i had to learn it the hardway wasting almost half of the day,
 hope it help to others..Thanks syed